# WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS + root

Tags: android, root

my application gives the user the option to grant root access to allow access to some system function (NFC). By default it never asks for root.

So, after permissions is granted, I figured it should work, but I am still getting the dreaded:

```
08-10 22:06:49.320: W/System.err(9421): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission required: Neither user 10174 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.
```

error. Am I missing something?
I am asking for the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission, so that can't be it.

The funny thing is I had NFC enable/ disable working, but after I installed a new Rom, I keep getting this error. It updated from 4.0.3 to 4.0.4, but no changes to the code in question as far as I can tell...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

You are missing the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission.

> I am asking for the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission, so that can't be it.

AFAIK, being root has nothing to do with permissions, directly. To hold `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`, your app must either be signed by the same signing certificate that signed the firmware *or* be installed on the system partition. Being root is neither of those things.

Comment: My application is installed in /system/app and this permissions is not being granted

Comment: presumably if you are rooted you could simply install the app in the system partition and then it would work?

Comment: @Michael: Correct. So, running as root does not immediately grant the permission, but it provides an avenue by which you can get the permission.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you can get your app to run as root. For example,
I got the `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission required` error when I ran:

```
String output = ProcessUtils.runProcess(MainService.this, "wm", "overscan", "0,0,10,10");
```

But I got around the issue (on a rooted device) via:

```
String output = ProcessUtils.runProcess(MainService.this, "su", "0", "sh", "-c", "wm overscan 0,0,10,10");
```