# Change system settings with android root app

Tags: android, settings, root

What is the best (most safe) way to change protected system settings like brightness, gps, data, ... within a root app?

I read about 2 ways to do so:

1) copy settings.db to your app folder manipulate it with sql api and then copy it back - 
seems more than just a bit risky to me.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392067/android-changing-the-system-settings-of-a-rooted-device-from-inside-the-app)

2) use root to copy your app to the system folder and hold WIRTE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission - seems doable, but does that break the market link, so the users won't receive updates anymore? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908599/write-secure-settings-root)

Or is there a different way?

Thx for your help!

Comment: @2) I found that updates through market are still possible, as android installs the updates on data partition but executes the app with system permissions.
The down sides are that 
-)the app will be uninstalled when custom rom users flash a new nightly and MOST BOTHERING: 
-)users can't uninstall the app without removing it from system partition before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of moving your app to `/system/app`, you can execute your "modification" commands as root using `su`
An explanation of how to do this using `Runtime.exec()` (and also one implementation) can be found [here](http://su.chainfire.eu/#how).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link. I read it a few times, still not 100 percent sure how i can modify system settings.
Does that mean if i open a super user session in a background thread and keep it active my app can hold system app permissions?
I know how to execute shell commands as super user, but i don't understand the mechanics of executing common code like Settings.System.putInt(...) as a system app.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well you cant execute "common" code like that because there is no way to notify the Android system that you now have root. It only allows that sort of access to apps that are signed as system apps. So you would need to implement that functionality yourself in combination with root. Like copying the file in question, editing those values with some sort of `SettingsEditor` and then copy it back using root. You can't just do `settingsApp.getSettings().set("brightness", "50")`, or anything like that if you're trying to access system info.

Comment: Ok, that's what i thought. Thank you.
How will android react if you replace the settings.db?
Is it ok to do that on the fly or do i have to take precautions?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think it would be okay since thats basically a resource that is loaded when the app opens, and as long as the `Settings` app is not running in the background.

Comment: I think the settings app is running permanently, this is why I'm not 100 percent sure this is a "clean" solution.