# What is the difference between a user app with root access and a system app in Android

Tags: android

The answer I am looking for is in the aspect of permissions.

Can a system app do everything ?
Can a user app with root access (ie on a rooted device) do everything?

If so, are they same?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, user app with root access have the same priority as the system apps (because you can modify system files), so i guess user app with root access can do almost "everything".

Comment: what do you mean by "everything"?

Comment: some of the things include, access to hide the application, remove the applications which came pre installed with mobile, feel free to add to this list.

Comment: @RethinavelPillai apps with root access can do the same thing like System apps, but you cant modify some setting because even System apps cannot do that. So by saying "everything" i mean everything that System apps can do, but not more.

Comment: @Arshak92 so for example use permission "WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" is possible if I have root access and not a system app?

Comment: @yanivps  i think answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908599/write-secure-settings-root